# How to recover deleted records with minimal downtime?

Tags: restore, db2, db2-luw

In an OLTP environment that cannot tolerate downtime, suppose if 100 records are deleted from a table, how do we recover them?

One way to recover the deleted records is to restore the database and/or tablespace then rollforward to point-in-time.

Comment: By "OLTP environment", do you mean an environment with zero downtime tolerance? Don't see how calling it OLTP or XYZ could prevent you from performing a restore otherwise.

Comment: Yes, downtime tolerance is ~zero ! Apart from online restore and rollforward to point-in-time, is there a better approach which you have come across.

Answer (score 4):

I believe DB2 Recovery Expert is the best option.

In the case of a dropped object, or recovery to a specific point in time, you should use the "Recovery" option.  The "undo SQL" option performs Log Analysis, which only affects data, not structure.

Please check IBM's official webpage : [DB2 Recovery Expert](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/db2recovery/index.html)

Comment: "the best" is a bit subjective, isn't it. For one, you must have had it installed _prior_ to the problem occurring. It also costs extra.

Comment: Starting from DB2 10.5 and later, the Recovery Expert license is embedded with the product. So no extra cost. 
Please check IBM official documentation for the products features (also check for 11.1): https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.licensing.doc/doc/r0053238.html

Comment: Had you actually read the link you posted? It clearly says that Recover Expert is part of Advanced Recovery Feature, which is sold separately.

Answer (score 2):

There is an API called `db2ReadLog()` that you can use to read transaction logs and collect information about deleted records.

IBM also sells a product called Recovery Expert that will help you do this and generate undo SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

Database or tablespace recovery is the only<sup>*</sup> way to go back in time and find deleted records if you haven't planned for this. To minimize the impact on the production environment you can always perform a restore on a different machine, export the records and import them in production. That does not require any downtime.

[HADR with delayed replay](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0060000.html), possibly in combination with [read-on-standby](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0054257.html), is another option. Obviously it needs to be set up *before* the error happens, so it's not suitable as an ad-hoc solution.

---

<sup>*</sup> If the table in question is a [system-period temporal table](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0058477.html), you will find the deleted records in its corresponding history table.